# How to return a result from login query string

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm getting a little lost with my mySQLi `bind_params` and other related methods. So far I have build a login script using a class structure.

```
$qu = $this->DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM CVUSERS WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
$qu->bind_params('ss',$username,$password);
```

Now this is where I'm getting lost. As a login script I want to make sure my query only has one result. How can I return an int or boolean from my query string?

```
bind_result($result);
if($result === 1){
    //this identical statement doesn't work :S
    //using an equals statements works for every entry. Even invalid ones.
    //I've found $result will always equal 1, there is more than one row in my table
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysqli's support for the prepared statements is quite ugly. So, you can't get your info an easy way.
For some reason it **always** require some strange function to call. That's where your doubts are from.
bind_result() will do literally nothing. it will start working only after you call fetch(). So you see in your code.

Another way is to select not count() but data itself as you did at first and check the number of rows returned. But it's still require another function call

```
$qu->execute();
$qu->store_result();
if($qu->num_rows){
    $this->_constructSessions($username);
}
```

However, If i were you, I'd make it more or less this way

```
$qu = $this->DBH->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CVUSERS WHERE username= ? AND password = ? ");
$qu->bind_param('ss',$username,$password);
$qu->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $res->fetch_array();
if($row){
    $this->_constructSessions($row);
}
```

But it's still toilsome and ugly.
That's why I never use native prepared statements. So, I make it with just

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM CVUSERS WHERE username=?s AND password=?s";
if ($row = $db->getRow($sql,$username,$password)) {
    $this->_constructSessions($row);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You've explained quiet a lot! I never realised you could write it like that. So much neater and smaller. would getRow return $row['username'] as my column? or is getRow not a method?

Answer (score 1):

From the PHP page for `mysqli_stmt::bind_result`:

`Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.`

So I would assume using:

```
if($result){
//no errors here! success! add additional code here
}
```

would work.

Comment: Thats what I would what thought but $result always = 1.

Comment: Are you sure the `$result` variable isn't a string? Since you're using `===` it has to be the same type. Have you tried `if($result === "1")`?

Comment: I've thought that might have been the case but it's defiantly an integer. I'm using `print_r($result);` and it's printing 1, every time lol no idea why. I am executing the query could that be a problem?

Comment: Hmm, then I really have no idea... Executing the query might be the problem. Try binding result, then comparing without executing the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below

```
if (($res = $qu->get_result())) {
    //so your query is right
    //now check how many rows return from your query
    if($res->num_rows > 0){
       //username and password exist so logged in
    }
    else { 
       //something wrong
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tired get_result() before and it's an undefined method. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you wrote this `$qu->execute()` ?

Comment: Yea under my bind_params();

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to be a little different to what I expected and I don't believe it's the correct answer to my question still. Thank you for your answers I'm sure they are are both correct but they didn't work for one reason or another :S. I would have used those methods myself anyway. 
I used this source code in the end:

```
//I used $resulte in case of redeclaration.
if($qu->fetch() && $resulte === 1){
    $this->_constructSessions($username);
}
else {
    //no access
}
```

I don't why but when using `if($result === 1)` the operation would always return false. So I presumed it was returning an string instead. But if you use `if($result == 1 && $qu->fetch())` the operation would return false again.

my whole code:

```
$qu = $this->DBH->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CVUSERS WHERE username= ? AND password = ? ");
$qu->bind_param('ss',$username,$password);
$qu->execute();
$qu->bind_result($resulte);     
if($qu->fetch() && $resulte === 1){
    $this->_constructSessions($username);
}
else {
    return array('error'=>true , 'content'=>'<div id="overlay"></div><div id="fail"><h1>Failed login</h1><p><a href="" id="newLogin">Click Here.</a> To request a new login</p><p><a href="" id="try">Or try again?</a></p></div>');
    sleep(1);
}
```

I'm still unsure why this operation works for this query and other don't. If any one can spot anything let me know.